# Proving and disproving $\exists b,c\in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=\frac a2x^2+bx+c $

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Let $f:I\to\mathbb R$ where $I$ is an interval, $f''(x)=a \ \ \forall x\in I$.
>
> 1. Prove that there exsits such numbers $b,c\in \mathbb R$ such that: $f(x)=\frac a2x^2+bx+c ,\ \forall x\in I$.
> 2. Show that the above statement is not necessarily true if $f:A\to\mathbb R$ and $f''(x)=a \ \ \forall x\in A$ where $A$ is not an interval.

I'm not sure I know how to prove 1, it's probably isn't enough to just derive $f(x)$ twice  and we can't integrate...

About 2. it means that the function isn't continuous but we see that it's still derivable so how can I find the relation between $b,c$ and $f$ ?

Comment: By a “section” you mean an “interval”?

Comment: @egreg yes. Translation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by “section” you mean an “interval”, then Lagrange's theorem is your friend.

Let $g=f'$; then you know that $g'(x)=a$, which is also the derivative of $h(x)=ax$. What do you know about functions defined on an interval which have the same derivative?

Then you can do similarly, because you know what $f'$ is.

For point 2, consider
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{ax^2}{2} & \text{if $0<x<1$}\\[2ex]
\dfrac{ax^2}{2}+1 & \text{if $2<x<3$}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: "What do you know about functions defined on an interval which have the same derivative ?" that both have the same slope at all points and both functions are the same except for a constant ?

Comment: @GinKin Yes; the fact about the slope is irrelevant here.

Comment: OK, that gives us the $c$ but what about the $b$ ?

Comment: @GinKin No, at the first stage you get the $b$.

Comment: I think I miss your point, the first stage is to use Lagrange ? So we get that for all points in the interval, any b will satisfy the derivative ?

Comment: @GinKin You have to do in two stages: first determine that $f'(x)$ has the form $f'(x)=ax+b$ (using the fact that its derivative is the constant $a$) and then go up to $f$ with a similar method.

Comment: I think I got it, I don't see how we used Lagrange here. Also, about 2. the defined function mean that there are two different b,c for the same function that answer the requirement ? There can be two different b,c in 1. as well...

Comment: @GinKin We used a consequence of Lagrange's theorem, namely that two functions defined on an interval that have the same derivative, differ by a constant. About "different $b$ and $c$ in 1”, I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: For 2, you defined a function that has b=0 and c=1 in one case and c=0 in the other case. As I understand, that shows that two different functions can have the same second derivative (?) and that disprove 1. If I understood right, why we can't define the same function for 1. and disprove it too ?

Comment: @GinKin Because that function wouldn't be differentiable.